# Apply align-text:center along with linear dimension

Tags: css, forms, html

I have the following div block:

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <form id="child" class="child"> <input  type="text" /> </form>
</div>
```

and `css`

```
.parent{
    margin:auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.child{
    width:200px;
    height:180px;
    background: grey;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/T9PvK/1/). Please explain me why when we apply to internal form `width` and `height` properties we lost the centering of the form into a div block, but safe the centering of form's content relative to form. Centering of `input` element will be safe even if we apply linear dimension to this. Actually: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/T9PvK/2/). I'm confused. 
Why behavior of this elements difference in our case?

Please give me a css specfication's quote if it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.parent{


    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.child{
    margin:auto;
    width:200px;
    height:180px;
    background: grey;
}
```

---

**Text-Align**

The text-align CSS property describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element. text-align does not control the alignment of block elements itself, only their inline content.

**Margin:auto**

The standard-compatible way to center a block itself without centering its inline content is setting the left and right margin to auto, e.g.:
margin:auto; or margin:0 auto; or  margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;

---

for more info. you can go through this link below

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

http://jsfiddle.net/T9PvK/6/

Comment: It works, thanks. But i dont understand why? It's realy magic for me. Please explain me why my example doesnt work and your example works correctly.

Comment: i have set the margin:auto in the child form which is to be centered..!!

Comment: I can read. Why without margin it doesnt work? From W3C: _The text-align property specifies the horizontal alignment of text in an element._ I'm repeat my question: _why when we apply to internal form width and height properties we lost the centering of the form into a div block, but safe the centering of form's content relative to form._